# How to plot a grid with different colors for certain points (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, plot, grid

**The problem**

I have a square grid with dimensions NxN and constant spacing between the grid points/nodes. I want to plot this grid, but some points are special and want them to be plotted in different color.

**Expectation**

The expected plot should look like that, but some blocks must have different color!

[image]

**Code**

My ridiculous and slow solution is given below:

```
N = 80;
x = 1:1:N;
y = 1:1:N;

rx = randi([1 80],1,1000); %represents the x coordinates of the special points 
ry = randi([1 80],1,1000); %represents the y coordinates of the special points 

[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = zeros(80,80);
figure(1)
surf(X,Y,Z);

%Abandon surf, use scatter instead
figure(2)
for i=1:N
    for j=1:N        
        plot(x(i),y(j),'bo');
        hold on
    end
end

for i=1:1000
    plot(rx(i),ry(i),'ro');
    hold on    
end
grid on
```

What is the correct way to do it because my eyes are bleeding? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The color is controlled by Z. So make Z a different value.

```
linear_indx=sub2ind([N,N],rx,ry);
Z(linear_indx)=1;
```

Change the colormap (or make your own) for a different set of colors. Or use `surf(X,Y,Z,C)`.

[image]

Comment: God. Of course it is controlled by Z. Thanks!

Comment: @Angelos no worries. To be fair, I think `imagesc` or `imshow` would be better options for this example, but I assume your real code may be a bit more complicated